# Displaying an object from express on seperate lines

Tags: json, express

I'm grabbing the data from the url and sending back an object with natural date and unix timestamp by using res.json(timeObj). The page displays this:

{"natural":"December 15, 2015","unix":1450137600}

Is there a way to res.json or res.send with this time object but to break it apart so that it displays like this on the page, or will it require routing to an html file and doing the formatting there?

```
{
 "natural":"December 15,2015",
 "unix":1450137600
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line in your app server:

```
app.set("json spaces", 4);
```

That should 'prettify' your json responses by adding 4 space nesting and line breaks.